# Why doesn't 'res.send()' redirect upon completion of MongoDB 'deleteMany' call?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

My call to Express's 'res.send(string)' fails to redirect and display the provided text upon completion of a call to MongoDB's 'deleteMany()'. The database is cleared and no error is thrown.

I've tried adjusting my call to 'res' with 'res.json()' and such, but to no avail. I've also adjusted the ordering my other calls within the 'delete' request, with no success. My inclination is that my issue is related to Promises.

```
    .delete(function(req, res){
            //if successful response will be 'complete delete successful'
            console.log('deleting all documents');
            MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (connectErr, client) => {
              if(connectErr) res.json({ "error": "Error connecting to database!", "error": connectErr });
              const db = client.db('test-db');
              try {
                db.collection('testCollection2').deleteMany({}, (err) => {
                  if(err) throw err;
                  res.send('complete delete successful');
                  console.log('complete delete successful');
                });
              } catch(err) {
                console.log('Complete delete failed!');
                res.send('Complete delete failed!');
              }
            });
          });
```

Despite not redirecting or receiving an error message, I still receive the console.log output confirming the successful call to 'deleteMany'. I'm not sure how to test this in more depth, since I'm using Glitch for the project. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How is this Express route called?  Via Javascript/Ajax?  If so, an Ajax call does not affect the page display in the browser at all unless you write Javascript code to look at the returned response and manually  change the content displayed or set a new URL for the page.   `res.send()` does not do a redirect at all.  All, it does is send a response to the current request.  It's up to the caller to decide what to do with that response when it's received.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't set up the front-end of what I'm working on and your comment helped me realize a little more clearly what's going on.

Comment: I know it's not related to what you're asking, but you're not gonna be able to catch an asychronous call like you're trying to. For callbacks, error handling code needs to happen within the callback. `try { setTimeout(() => { throw new Error("foo") }) } catch (err) { console.log("error won't be caught")}`.

Comment: I'm a little confused what types of errors I would expect to handle with the catch in this case? I went back and made sure all my callbacks handle errors internally. Should these errors be handled differently, say through Express's 'next' function? Thanks for the suggestion.